# Substitute for MathLink to integrate PARI with Mathematica?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, librarylink, external-calls

How does one access MathLink with current version of Mathematica?

I'm trying to integrate the "computer algebra system" PARI with Mathematica, as documented at https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/mathlink.html . But command

when I try to establish the link inside Mathematica with

```
<< MathLink`
```

fails with a "Cannot open MathLink`", and

```
Install["./parishell",LinkMode->Launch]
```

fails with "Could not find MathLink executable."
(parishell is the PARI script shown in https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/mathlink.html)

How establish the linkage?